# Fixing integer overflow in expression leads to an unexpected behavior

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

Please consider the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    size_t a = 1024ull * 1024ull * 1024ull * 2ull;
    std::cout << "1024ull * 1024ull * 1024ull * 2ull = " << a << std::endl;

    size_t b = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2;
    std::cout << "1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2 = " << b << std::endl;

    size_t c = 18446744071562067968u;
    std::cout << "18446744071562067968u = " << c << std::endl;

    size_t d = 1ULL << 31;
    std::cout << "1ULL << 31 = " << d << std::endl;

    size_t e = 1 << 31;
    std::cout << "1 << 31 = " << e << std::endl;

    std::cout << "max size_t = " << std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()
              << std::endl;
}
```

When I build it with GCC or Clang I see the following warning:

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 ./main.cpp
./main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
./main.cpp:8:35: warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]
     size_t b = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2;
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

However, when I run the code, only the "wrong" version produces the correct result:

```
1024ull * 1024ull * 1024ull * 2ull = 2147483648
1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2 = 18446744071562067968
18446744071562067968u = 18446744071562067968
1ULL << 31 = 2147483648
1 << 31 = 18446744071562067968
max size_t = 18446744073709551615
```

GCC version:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Clang version:

```
clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

Is there any sane explanation for this behavior?

Closed: 2147483648 is the right result.

Comment: I'm not sure `b` can work, as yes, that will overflow `int`.

Comment: Which one do you mean is the wrong version with the correct result? `1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2 = 18446744071562067968` does not look correct to me, and that's the one the compiler warns about.

Comment: I wonder not why `b` works but why `a` and `d` don't :)

Comment: @fsquirrel, works in which regard? shouldn't `1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2` be `2147483648`?

Comment: @ilkkachu, you're right, I'll close this one.

Comment: @fsquirrel, Bathsebas answer is right, though on why it overflows, and what appears to happen to give that result

Answer (score 3):

The expression

```
1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2
```

(which algebraically is `2147483648`) is made up of `int` types. That will overflow a 32 bit `int`, and the behaviour on doing that is *undefined*. Note that the direct assignment of `2147483648` to a 32 bit `int` is *implementation defined* up to and including C++17 and defined from C++20, but you haven't done that.

The observed behavior is consistent with the expression being equal to `INT_MIN` on a 32 bit 2's complement platform and that converted to a 64 bit `std::size_t`, but **don't** rely on that behaviour.

Comment: FWIW, C++20 is out, and if the OP is using it, then it is no longer UB.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Very good point. C++20 is a quantum leap forward in this respect. I'll be moving my codebases to it in the near term.

Comment: I'm very happy they just decided to mandate the behavior. It get it reduces flexibility, but the "safety" gain is a win in my book.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Despite the impression I like to give on this site, I haven't used a 1's complement machine, or a non-ASCII encoded machine since University. And such machines still have C++11. (C++14 mandates 2's complement `signed char`.)

Comment: `behaviour on doing that is undefined up to and including C++17` Signed arithmetic overflow is UB also in C++20 `don't rely on that behaviour until C++20.` Don't rely on this behaviour of signed overflow in C++20 either.

Comment: @eerorika; You sure? That's at odds with what NathanOliver says. I'll roll back.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yup. It's just the thing that you describe as *implementation defined* in the answer that has become defined by the standard in C++20.